# How to determine continuity of a solution of an ODE on data?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, continuity

I'm having some trouble understanding what this question is asking for.

Given a system modeled by the IVP:

$$
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{aligned}
y'+2y=at,\ 0<t \le T\ and \ a,b \gt 0 \\ 
y(0)=b \\
\end{array}
\right. 
$$

The question asks to show how the solution depends continously on $(a,b)$.

In particular, it asks to show that

$$
\max_{0 \le t \le T} \lvert y_1(t)-y_2(t)\rvert \le \epsilon 
$$

provided

$$
\lvert a_1-a_2\rvert \le  \frac {2\epsilon}{\lvert 2T-1+e^{-2T}\rvert}
$$
and
$$
\lvert b_1-b_2\rvert \le \epsilon
$$

So far, I've solved for the general solution to the IVP. Next, I substituted $a$ and $b$ for $(a_1,b_1)$ and $(a_2,b_2)$ for $y_1$ and $y_2$, respectively.

I'm unclear as to what I should do next. In order to find the maximum difference, I was thinking about taking the first derivative of $\lvert y_1(t)-y_2(t)\rvert$, setting it equal to zero, and then finding the $t$ value for which the difference is maximized. However, that still leaves the problem of $\epsilon$. How am I supposed to find a concrete value for $\epsilon$? Is this even the corret path to take to solve the problem?

I'm not looking for a solution, I would just like some clarifaction of the question and guidance on how to proceed.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose $y_1$ is a solution to ODE with corresponding parameters $(a_1, b_1)$ and $y_2$ is a solution to the ODE with parameters $(a_2, b_2)$ on a uniform interval $[0, T]$ (let us also assume $T>1$).

It's easy to see 
\begin{align}
y_i(t) = b_ie^{-2t} + \frac{a_i}{4}(2t-1+e^{-2t})
\end{align}
for $i=1, 2$.

Now, let us consider the difference of $y_1$ and $y_2$. Observe, we have the estimate
\begin{align}
|y_1(t) - y_2(t)| \leq&\ \left|b_1-b_2\right|e^{-2t} + \frac{1}{4}|a_1-a_2||2t-1+e^{-2t}|\\
\leq&\ |b_1 - b_2| + \frac{1}{4}|a_1-a_2||2T-1+e^{-2T}| 
\end{align}
which holds uniformly for all $t\in [0, T]$. In particular, it follow
\begin{align}
\max_{t \in [0, T]}|y_1(t)-y_2(t)| \leq |b_1 - b_2| + \frac{1}{4}|a_1-a_2||2T-1+e^{-2T}|. 
\end{align}

Edit: I realize you didn't want the solution after I finished writing the post.

To summarize the issue, what you are actually trying to do for this problem is to show the mapping $F: \mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R} \longmapsto C([0,T]\rightarrow \mathbb{R})$ defined by
\begin{align}
(a, b)\longmapsto y_{a, b}(t)
\end{align}
is continuous. To word this in terms of elementary metric space language: For a fixed $\epsilon>0$, you want to find a $\delta>0$ such that 
\begin{align}
|| F(a_1, b_1) - F(a_2, b_2)||_{C([0, T]\rightarrow \mathbb{R})} = \max_{t\in [0, T]}|y_{a_1, b_1}(t)-y_{a_2, b_2}(t)|<\epsilon
\end{align}
whenever $|(a_1, b_1) - (a_2, b_2)| <\delta$. In your problem, they want you to show that 
\begin{align}
\delta=\min\left( \epsilon, \frac{2\epsilon}{|2T-1+e^{-2T}|}\right)
\end{align} 
will work.

Comment: Why is it possible to set $\epsilon$ equal to $\lvert b_1−b_2\rvert e^{−2t}+ \frac14 \lvert a_1−a_2\rvert \lvert 2t−1+e^{−2t}\rvert$?

Comment: Actually, you are given an arbitrary $\epsilon>0$. Have you taken I course in elementary real analysis ?

Comment: The reason I ask is because the above proof is just an $\epsilon-\delta$ argument.

Comment: No. This is for an ODE class. My professor is giving us some pretty tricky problem sets.